# Сохранение в файле настроек (Preferences) ссылки на Окно (Activity)

Tags: android, activity, android-preferences

Всем хорошего настроения! В приложении есть несколько окон (Activity). При выходе пользователя из приложения необходимо запомнить, какое окно пользователь просматривал последним, и при повторном запуске приложения показывать ему его, а не MainActivity. Если я ошибаюсь, подправьте, - логика такая: при уничтожении Окна в файл настройки (Preferences) записывается ЧТО-ТО, что потом из этого же файла при создании MainActivity читается и запускается требуемое окно. Не известно, что нужно записать, чтобы потом вызвать окно намерением (Intent).

Comment: Любой идентификатор сохраняете, например порядковый номер какой то .. затем по этому номеру вызывайте нужный интент.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что не существует как таковой ПРЯМОЙ ссылки на класс, который можно было бы записать в файл настроек?

Comment: @St-st а зачем прямая ссылка? pavloff вам всё верно подсказал

Comment: @Андроид Андроид дополнительный вопрос задал для лучшего понимания устройства андроидного мира, и моих возможностей в нем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ну можно записать какое-то значение в SharedPreference и допустим сделать такое условие:

```
if(вытаскиваем значение из кэша){
StartActivity такое-то
}
```

Правда если оч много Activity, то это будет громоздкое решение... но для небольшого кол-ва Activity сойдет.

Comment: Благодарю. Через switch будет красивее.